# how to export data from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to fetch some data from database and those data will be  downloadable in text format.

For that I am using

```
<?php
$filename="abc.txt";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
echo "PHP is awesome";
?>
```

The above code is providing the option to download a file.

But when I am trying to add database connection in code that time I am not getting the download option. So I need help to solve the above problem.

My error Code:

```
<?php
$filename="abc.txt";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
$name="JONE":
$db_host =hostname;
$db_user =username;
$db_pass =password;
echo "$name";
mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass );
$sql_query="select * from order";
echo "$sql_query";
$result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
while ( $array = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
   echo "$array[0]\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why should the code with the MySQL connection open a download dialog? If you compare your two code snippets, you will notice that the first one sets some headers, the second one doesn't.

Comment: I am extreamly sorry for putting wrong code. while copy pasting ,I missed some part. Sorry for wasting your valuable time .

Comment: this is exactly what you need: 
http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/

Comment: @Arijit No problem, such things happen from time to time. :-)

Comment: @DanielKrom--- Thanks for your reply.In the your link ,I do not able to under stand `$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');` part. In path what path is required . Can you give one example.

Comment: `$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');` opens the output stream as a file resource. It allows you to "echo" things by writing them there. This is needed because `fputcsv` always writes to a file.

Comment: @DanielKrom - I tried that example. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

which PHP version used?

The mysql extension is deprecated in php 5 later

PHP 5 and later can work with a MySQL database using:

MySQLi extension (the "i" stands for improved)

PDO (PHP Data Objects)

Earlier versions of PHP used the MySQL extension. However, this extension was deprecated in 2012.

if you used php new version and mysql

you can try for your code

```
<?php
$filename="abc.txt";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
$name="JONE";
$DBServer = 'localhost'; // e.g 'localhost' or '192.168.1.100'
$DBUser   = 'root';
$DBPass   = 'root';
$DBName   = 'sms';
echo "$name";
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error,
  E_USER_ERROR);
} 

$sql_query="select * from tmd_news";
$rs=$conn->query($sql_query);

if($rs === false) {
trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql_query . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, 
E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
 $arr = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
foreach($arr as $row) {
echo $row['news_id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP version is : 5.5.9. I tried but it is not working.

Comment: which error show try with my code? please can you show me.

Comment: with your code the download option is not coming .So I converted `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");` to `header("Content-Type: text/csv");` for test purpose. and in output i am getting only `JONE`.

Comment: i modify my code mysql to mysqli and please try again. This code ok for me and show result in abc.txt file.

Comment: I tried it again . again i am getting same kind of problem